# Animated cosine waveform with FM modulation using the animate package

Tags: pgfplots, animate

I would like to get some help to get an animation of a modulated FM signal like this:

[image]

Here is the code that I have so far:

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{animate}[2014/11/27]

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[
  %poster=1, % sin 2x (frames are numbered in zero-based manner)
  width=12cm,
  height=6cm,
  label=graph_switch,
  begin={\begin{tikzpicture}},
  end={\end{tikzpicture}},
  step
]{0}

% Carrier Signal
  \begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    %xlabel={$x$},
    %ylabel={$\text{sin}(x)$},
    xmin=-4*pi,xmax=4*pi]
    \addplot[black,samples=101] {5*cos(x*180./pi)};
  \end{axis}

% Modulating Signal
    \begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    %xlabel={$x$},
    %ylabel={$\text{sin}(x)$},
    xmin=-4*pi,xmax=4*pi]
    \addplot[blue,samples=501] {5*cos(6*x*180./pi)};
  \end{axis}

% Modulated Signal
    \begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    %xlabel={$x$},
    %ylabel={$\text{sin}(x)$},
    xmin=-4*pi,xmax=4*pi]
    \addplot[red,samples=501] {5*cos(x*180./pi)*5*cos(6*x*180./pi)};
  \end{axis}


\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for an AM example. (For FM, see [↗follow-up Q](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440425).)

The plotted equations were modified somewhat (acc. to Wikipedia page on [↗Amplitude Modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation)).

Here is an approach using the **`xsavebox`** package. This saves final PDF file size and a lot of compilation time.

1. We save one cycle `[0:pi]` of the base signal into an `xlrbox`, outside `animateinline`.
2. Then, the animation is created by moving 5 cycles in a window of 4 cycles width.

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% uncomment \def\export{} below to export animation
%% to multipage PDF a.pdf and run
%% 
%%  convert -density 300 -delay 4 -loop 0 -alpha remove a.pdf b.gif
%%
%% to get an animated GIF b.gif at 100/4 = 25 frames per s
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\def\export{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ifdefined\export
  \documentclass[export]{standalone}
\else
  \documentclass{standalone}
\fi

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{xsavebox} % xlrbox
\usepackage{calc} % \widthof{...}, \real{...}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
%
%save ONE cycle in an xlrbox
\begin{xlrbox}{OneCycle}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      hide axis,
      x=1cm,y=1cm,
      /tikz/line cap=rect, /tikz/line join=round
    ]
      \addplot[domain=0:pi,black,samples=250] {0.8*cos(x*2*180/pi)};
      \addplot[domain=0:pi,blue,samples=500] {cos(x*20*180/pi)-2};
      \addplot[domain=0:pi,red,samples=500] {(1+0.8*cos(x*2*180/pi))*cos(x*20*180/pi)-5};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{xlrbox}%
%
\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{10}
  \multiframe{18}{i=0+1}{
    \makebox[\widthof{\theOneCycle}*\real{4}][l]{% window = FOUR cycles
      \makebox[\widthof{\theOneCycle}/\real{18}*\real{-\i}]{}% offset
      \theOneCycle\theOneCycle\theOneCycle\theOneCycle\theOneCycle% moving FIVE cycles 
    }
  }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution.  How do you save the image directly to a gif file?  Thanks!

Comment: The plotted functions have been adjusted a bit according to Wikipedia. Gif creation explained in the code.

Answer (score 6):

Like this? I added the controls for debugging, you can set `step` or `autoplay` as you wish.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{animate}[2014/11/27]

\usepackage{amsmath}

\tikzset{
    declare function={
        carrier(\t) = cos(\t);
        modulator(\t) = cos(6*\t);
    },
}

\pgfmathsetmacro\StepSize{10}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\NumFrames{360/\StepSize}

\newcommand{\drawModulatedAM}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\PhaseShift{#1*\StepSize}
        \begin{axis}[
            hide axis,
            scale only axis,
            width = 12cm,
            height = 6cm,
            xmin=-360,
            xmax=360,
        ]
            \addplot[domain=-360:360,black,samples=101] {carrier(x+\PhaseShift)};
            \addplot[domain=-360:360,blue,samples=501] {modulator(x+\PhaseShift)-2.5};
            \addplot[domain=-360:360,red,samples=501] {modulator(x+\PhaseShift)*carrier(x+\PhaseShift) - 5};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{animateinline}[label=graph_switch,controls]{10}
        \multiframe{\NumFrames}{iFrame=0+1}{\drawModulatedAM{\iFrame}}
    \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]