# Animated cosine waveform with FM modulation using the animate package part 2

Tags: pgfplots, animate

This question is building off the elegant solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440281/animated-cosine-waveform-with-fm-modulation-using-the-animate-package).

I have updated the equations.  For a Frequency Modulated (FM) signal, these are the equations:

`Carrier = cos(2*pi*fc*t)`

`Modulation = sin(2*pi*fm*t)`

`FM = cos(2*pi*fc*t+5*sin(2*pi*fm*t))`

I am trying to get the FM of this plot:

[image]

Instead, I get this:
[image]

Can you assist me in getting the correct output?  Thank you!

This is the code that I modified from the original solution:

**Code**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{xsavebox} % xlrbox
\usepackage{calc} % \widthof{...}, \real{...}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
%
%save two cycles in an xlrbox
\begin{xlrbox}{TwoCycles}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
      \addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi,black,samples=501] {sin(x*2*180/pi)};
      \addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi,blue,samples=501] {cos(x*10*180/pi)-2.5};
      \addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi,red,samples=501] {cos(x*10*180/pi + 5*sin(x*2*180/pi))-5};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{xlrbox}%
%
\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop,width=12cm,height=6cm]{10}
  \multiframe{36}{i=0+1}{
    \makebox[\widthof{\theTwoCycles}][l]{% window
      \makebox[\widthof{\theTwoCycles}/\real{72}*\real{-\i}]{}% offset
      \theTwoCycles\theTwoCycles%
    }
  }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trigonometric functions of PGF expect their argument in degrees. Thus, the whole argument must be multiplied by `180/pi` for the third plotted curve.

Moreover, the size was a bit further optimized by saving only one cycle `[0:pi]` of the base signal in an `xlrbox`, and then moving five cycles in a window of four cycles width. The line join was set to `round` to prevent sparks from occurring in the plots.

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% uncomment \def\export{} below to export animation
%% to multipage PDF a.pdf and run
%% 
%%  convert -density 300 -delay 4 -loop 0 -alpha remove a.pdf b.gif
%%
%% to get an animated GIF b.gif at 100/4 = 25 frames per s
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\def\export{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ifdefined\export
  \documentclass[export]{standalone}
\else
  \documentclass{standalone}
\fi

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{xsavebox} % xlrbox
\usepackage{calc} % \widthof{...}, \real{...}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
%
%save ONE cycle in an xlrbox
\begin{xlrbox}{OneCycle}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      hide axis,
      x=1cm,y=1cm,
      /tikz/line cap=rect, /tikz/line join=round
    ]
      \addplot[domain=0:pi,black,samples=250] {cos(x*2*180/pi)};
      \addplot[domain=0:pi,blue,samples=500] {cos(x*20*180/pi)-2.5};
      \addplot[domain=0:pi,red,samples=500] {cos((x*20 + 6*sin(x*2*180/pi))*180/pi)-5};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{xlrbox}%
%
\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{10}
  \multiframe{18}{i=0+1}{
    \makebox[\widthof{\theOneCycle}*\real{4}][l]{% window = FOUR cycles
      \makebox[\widthof{\theOneCycle}/\real{18}*\real{-\i}]{}% offset
      \theOneCycle\theOneCycle\theOneCycle\theOneCycle\theOneCycle% moving FIVE cycles 
    }
  }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution!  Sincerely appreciated.  Is there a way to output the gif file directly as how you did to post the graphic in your solution?  Thanks again!

Comment: Uncomment the code section as explained in the updated code and use `convert` from ImageMagick.org. Now, I used `x` and `y` to scale the plot (same unit in *x* and *y*).